# Is there a way to evaluate individual Msil instructions?

Tags: c#, cil, dnlib

Background:
I am using dnlib to build a deobfuscator for an unknown custom done Obfuscator in c#. The obfuscated code has large amount of mathematical expressions that define constants for things such as a switch statement, if statements, numbers for method calls, ect. This is part of the control flow obfusctation as well.

Problem:
Since I have all these expressions that need to be evaluated, I need to find a way to traverse through the msil instructions of a given method, and emulate the results that appear on the stack of the method.
For example, let's say I have an expression of if (5 + 9)
In msil, the expression will be
Ldci4.5
Ldci4 9
add

What I need to do is have my own little runtime with its own stack that can be reinitialized upon each method I attempt to deobfuscate. This runtime can evaluate each instruction and it's effects on the local stack of the method. This way I can evaluate simple expressions like the instructions above. I can then nop those instructions and put the actual value back into the physical code.
I know I can pretty easily make a class to act as how the stack does, but I'm not sure how I would go about taking an Instruction instance from dnlib, and giving it a way to evaluate that in connection with a stack class.

This is the closest thing to what I'm describing that I could find on the internet
https://github.com/GodLesZ/ConfuserDeobfuscator/blob/master/ConfuserDeobfuscator/ConfuserDeobfuscator/Utils/ILEmulator.cs

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't help thinking, the reason the code is obfuscated is because the creator didn't want anyone to decompile it.   What you want to do is probably against any kind of licence you have been granted.

Comment: One way is to generate functions at runtime with `System.Reflection.Emit` and evaluate them. Unfortunately compiling function will take some time. Making assembly collectible may help with memory leaks